# Forall statement applied for a subset of elements in PDDL Domain?

Tags: forall, planning, pddl

### Case of use

First of all, I want to explain my case of use: I want to divide a field in different sectors and all plants should be analyzed by robots (just one robot per sector). I want to check in :preconditions that all plants for one sector are already analyzed, so that the robot return to the 'home'.

### Problem

Here is the domain PDDL. My problem is placed in the preconditions of "tracker-back-home" action. Now I am checking if all the plants have been already analyzed, but I need to know if all the plants **of the specific sector *?s*** are analyzed. It is possible to do using forall statement?

```
(define (domain killbee)
(:requirements :strips :typing)
(:types 
  bee location - object
  ;Inheritance
  tracker - bee
  hive plant sector - location
)
(:predicates 
  (directly-connected ?l1 - location ?l2 - location)
  (at ?l1 - object ?l2 - object) ;location is hive, plant or sector
  (free-sector ?s - sector)
  (bee-with-sector ?b - tracker)
  (tracker-ready-to-move ?b - tracker)
  (analyzed-plant ?p - plant ?s - sector)
  (sector-tracked ?s - sector)
  (plant-in-sector ?p - plant ?s - sector)
)
...
...
(:action tracker-back-home
:parameters (?b - tracker ?p - plant ?h - hive ?s - sector)
:precondition 
  (and (tracker-ready-to-move ?b)
  (at ?b ?p)
  (not (at ?b ?h))
  (forall (?x - plant) (analyzed-plant ?x ?s)))
  )
:effect 
  (and 
  (not (at ?b ?p))
  (at ?b ?h)
  (sector-tracked ?s)
  (not (bee-with-sector ?b))
  (free-sector ?s))
)...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you check out the language feature "imply" as defined by PDDL 2.1? (Maybe it was already defined before 2.1 -- not sure.) With it, you can define:

```
(forall (?pPrime - plant)
  (imply (at ?s ?pPrime) (analyzed-plant ?pPrime ?s))
)
```

Note: I am not sure whether the order of parameters in `(at ?s ?pPrime)` is correct. It's supposed to encode that the plant `?pPrime` is in sector `?s`.

The condition expands to a large set of implications reading that for all plants `p'` (no matter where they are) holds: "`if plant p' is in s, then it's analyzed in s`". This should encode exactly what you are looking for.

Comment: It totally worked. Just to mention the condition in 'imply' statement is (plant-in-sector ?pPrime ?s). Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean that it should read "(plant-in-sector ?pPrime ?s)" instead of "(at ?s ?pPrime)" in the imly statement? I was restricting to those predicates that are defined in your example. "plant-in-sector" does not exist there.

Comment: You are right that predicate is missing, I have updated the post with it. The solution is: (forall (?pPrime - plant)
    (imply (plant-in-sector ?pPrime ?s) (analyzed-plant ?pPrime ?s))
  )